# create multiple branch from one trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i trying to create multiple branch from trunk , but after creating branch1 if i creating branch2 ,  branch1 source code also getting copy inside branch 2 . [image]

can anyone help me what is correct way to create multiple branch from trunk . 
Thanks

Comment: Subversion branches are not first class elements, they're just regular directories. Haven't you noticed that you have `Branches` **inside** `Trunk`?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other version control systems, branches are not first class elements or, in other words, Subversion does not have tags and branches among its feature set. Instead, they are *emulated* with regular directories, under the assumption that [copies are cheap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395689/svn-when-you-tag-a-working-copy-is-it-still-a-cheap-copy#2395699). So you branch and tag just like you'd organise your files in your computer.

In your case, you have this peculiar directory structure:

```
Testing11
       \_ Trunk
             \_ Branches
                      \_ Dev_Bhavana
                                  \_ Branches
                                           \_ t1
                                           \_ t2
```

No wonder that you can't figure out what its directory contains. You only need to do some clean-up.

Last but not least, Subversion does not enforce any directory structure, but suggests a [Repository Layout](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion_repo) based in these directory names:

- trunk
- branches
- tags

Pros:

- It's automatically obvious for any programmer who joins the team
- Some client tools (such as TortoiseSVN) recognise these names and offer you specific features (such as a warning when committing changes to a tag).